# Sobolev embedding if $p=3/2$, $n=3$ and $k=2$

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Usually, Sobolev's embedding theorem goes as follows. Suppose $1\leq p<q < \infty$ and $k> \ell$. If

$$ \frac{1}{p} - \frac{k}{n} = \frac{1}{q} - \frac{\ell}{n} ,$$

then $W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset W^{\ell,q}$. In the case $p=n$, $k=1$ we have $W^{1,n}(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset BMO$. I was wondering what happens in the case $p=\frac{3}{2}$, $n=3$ and $k=2$? This, applied to the formula above, yields

$$0 =  \frac{1}{q} - \frac{\ell}{3}$$

So, intuitively, $W^{2,3/2}$ should be contained in something close to $L^{\infty}$ (being the case $\ell=0$, $q= \infty$). But what is it exactly?

Comment: I am confused. To get $0$ on the lhs, we need (for $n = 3$ and $k = 2$) $p = 3/2$. And then, $W^{2,3/2} \subset W^{1,3} \subset BMO$.

Comment: @gerw Sorry, I phrased the question in a way that made it incomprehensible. It should be clearer now.

Comment: My answer is still valid.

Comment: Yes and I'm very grateful for it ;)